# Publicly available Web proxy forward cache logs/data sets

Tags: proxy, public, logging, squid

I'm looking to do some analysis on HTTP requests that occur between clients and web servers.  Are there any recent (at least within last 4 years) publicly available data sets of web proxy forward cache logs, such as those recorded by a Squid proxy?  I'm most interested in forward cache HTTP log data - so coming from a cache that sits between many clients and many servers.  I'd have an auxiliary interest in reverse proxy data, such as a proxy that serves up HTTP responses on behalf of a single server, though a proxy log that spans many clients and many servers would be preferable.

I'm after basically as much data as I can get and the larger the number of clients represented in the data the better.  I imagine universities/large corporations might have such data logs, though haven't been able to find any publicly available (and hence this question).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It used to be quote common, e.g., the NLANR traces, the DEC traces, etc. However, in the last few years no-one seems willing to share traces, perhaps because of privacy concerns (even with anonymisation of the client ip, cookies and URL).

See http://www.web-caching.com/traces-logs.html for some older ones.